Mailu email server: Let’s Encrypt does not request new certificate automatically
Using Mailu docker image, I built an email server on Debian 12.
Whenever the certificate expires, I use docker compose down and docker compose up command so certificate will be renewed.
What I expected:
I expected the certificate to be renewed before expiration automatically whether by Mailu or other ways like using Certbot.
What I tried (1):
I tried the work around here:
Managing of external Let’s Encrypt certificates
After installing certbot using apt and running renew command manully, I got this message:
# renew_certificates.sh file 
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/mailu/privkey.pem /mailu/certs/live/mailu/privkey.pem || exit 1
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/mailu/fullchain.pem /mailu/certs/live/mailu/fullchain.pem || exit 1
docker exec mailu_front_1 nginx -s reload

root@srv2790559099:/home# certbot renew --deploy-hook /home/renew_certificates.sh
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
No renewals were attempted.
No hooks were run.

I think this is because the certificate is generated by Mailu image not certbot that I installed on the system.
What I tried (2):
I also struggle to understand this quote from the document to check why the certificate doesn't get renewed. I chose letsencrypt while setting up here:

When you are not using the embedded letsencrypt option from Mailu, you cannot make use of it’s symlink functionality in the letsencrypt/live directory.


I think this is because the certificate is generated by Mailu image not certbot that I installed on the system. really? What about inspecting the script that you are running, and looking at the commands that are executed? Or just run the certbot commands manually?

Have you read the documentation?

@GregAskew I mean Mailu has an internal Certbot that creates or renews them during docker down and docker up and I wonder why it doesn't renew automatically before the expiration date.
If I install Certbot directly, I should create new certs with my external Certbot. this way, the cert will be renewed.
